# How to update data if product sku already available in magento using custom script for product import?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, import, model, csv

I have created custom import script for simple product csv import in magento. It is working fine for the newly products. 
But I want to update the products if sku already exists. 
How can I achieve this? I am using the below code :

```
<?php  
error_reporting(0);

ini_set('max_execution_time', 2000);
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento

umask(0);

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(0)); 
$data = glob("customupload/*.csv");  
$fileList = array();
foreach ($data as $file) {
    $fileList[filemtime($file)] = $file;
}
ksort($fileList);
$myarray = array();
foreach($fileList as $key => $val){
    $myarray[] = $val;
}
$list=array();
if(count($myarray)){

    /*This will create an array of associative arrays with the first row column headers as the keys.*/
    $csv_map = array_map('str_getcsv', file($myarray[count($myarray)-1]));
    $list = explode('/', $myarray[count($myarray)-1]);
    array_walk($csv_map, function(&$a) use ($csv_map) {
        $a = array_combine($csv_map[0], $a);
    });

    array_shift($csv_map); # remove column header
    /*End*/

    $message = '';
    $count   = 1;
    foreach($csv_map as $data){
        try {

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 

        $entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')
                        ->setType('catalog_product')
                        ->getTypeId();
        $attributeSetName   = $data['attribute set'];
        $attributeSetId     = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
                                ->getCollection()
                                ->setEntityTypeFilter($entityTypeId)
                                ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_name', $attributeSetName)
                                ->getFirstItem()
                                ->getAttributeSetId();

        $product->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId); // need to look this up 

        $product->setTaxClassId(0); // taxable goods

        $product->setVisibility(4); // catalog, search

        $product->setStatus(1); // enabled

        $product->setWebsiteIDs(1); 

        $product->setStoreId(1);    

        $product->setTypeId('simple');

        $product->setWarranty('Lifetime');

        // assign product to the default website
        $product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));  


        // configure stock
        $product->setStockData(array(
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 1, // use global config ?
            'manage_stock'            => 0, // shoudl we manage stock or not?
            'is_in_stock'             => 1 
            /*'qty'                     => 2,*/
        ));  
        $mediaArray = array(
            'thumbnail'   => $data['image'],
            'small_image' => $data['image'],
            'image'       => $data['image']
        );

        // Remove unset images, add image to gallery if exists
        $importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/product/';

        foreach ( $mediaArray as $imageType => $fileName ) {
            $filePath = $importDir . $fileName;
            if ( file_exists($filePath) ) {
                try {
                    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, $imageType, false);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
            } else {
                echo "Product does not have an image or the path is incorrect. Path was: {$filePath}<br/>";
            }
        }
        //set category

        $_category = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')->addFieldToFilter('name', $data['Category'])->getFirstItem();

        $cat1= $_category->getId();
        $expcategory = explode('/',$data['sub category']); 
        $allsubcatid = array();

        foreach($expcategory as $_cat2) 
        {

            $_category = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')->addFieldToFilter('name', $_cat2)->getFirstItem();

            $allsubcatid[] = $_category->getId(); 

        } 
        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($allsubcatid);die;
        $product->setCategoryIds(array($cat1,$allsubcatid));

        $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', 'manufacturer');
        $attributeValue = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
                        ->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getData('attribute_id'))
                        ->setStoreFilter(0, false);
         foreach($attributeValue as $option)    
        {
            if (strtolower($option['value']) == strtolower($data['manufacturer'])) {
                $manufacturer =  $option['option_id'];
            }
        }
        // finally set custom data

        foreach($data as $key => $val){ 
            if($key != 'Category'){
                $capitalword = ucwords(trim($key));
                $remove_hyphen = str_replace(' ','',trim($capitalword)); 
                $setdata = $remove_hyphen; 
                $setdatas = set.$setdata; 
                $product->$setdatas($val); 
            }
        }
        $product->setManufacturer($manufacturer);   
        $product->save();

        }catch (Exception $e) {

            Mage::log($e->getMessage(), null, 'configurableProductsDataError.log', true);
        }
        $count++;
        $c .= $count."<br>"; 
        if($count ==1){ break; } 
    }

        echo "Success";
}

?>
 <?php

rename("customupload/".$list[1], "customupload/uploaded/".$list[1]);
?>
```

Comment: Where you create product model there ,check product is existing,by checking like $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadBySku($sku); and put that $ product in if condition and if product already then no need to create product model direct use $product and set value to it and save that

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$data['sku']);
```

Or

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->load($product->getIdBySku($data['sku']));
```

If the product is found it will load the product and return you the model. If not it will return you an empty model.